# gulp serve - Error: Cannot find module './build/bindings/encode.node'

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, gulp, mean-stack, angular-fullstack

try to install on my AWS EC2 ubuntu server the angular-fullstack framework found in here [angular-fullstack](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack)

Getting this error after running `'gulp serve'`:

```
module.js:471 throw err;
Error: Cannot find module './build/bindings/encode.node' at ...
```

on my mac os everything works fine. I only getting this error on my ubuntu server.

Help? Please!!!

Some information:

Operation system : Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Have you tried installing `node-gyp` globally? Have you tried `node-gyp rebuild` inside the errant modules folder?

Comment: I am seeing the same error: https://pastebin.com/yVR2bGxe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This means that the module failed to build properly when you did an `npm install` on your project. An install inside the module's directory *should* fix this:

```
$ (cd node_modules/iltorb && npm i)
```

Comment: Hi

now i get this error at the same step (when runinng 'gulp serve'):    Error: Cannot find module '/home/ubuntu/projects/mean-test-v5/node_modules/node-zopfli/lib/binding/node-v48-linux-x64/zopfli.node'

Comment: @DaniBanai do the same for the other module: `$ cd node_modules/node-zopfli && npm i && cd ../..`

Comment: I used the same setup as noted in your [Issue 2553](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/2553), and running npm install in both the iltorb & node-zopfli directories resulted in successful compilations and I was able to run your project.

Comment: Thank for everything

Comment: @DaniBanai you're welcome. I assume this means you were able to get both of these modules working?

Comment: I gust deleted everything. created new server. i didn't install node-gyp. works :)